# Number of Function Calls In Recursive Code

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, computability, recursion

I am new to recursion. I am doing some practice questions and I was wondering what the technique is for going from some recursive code to identifying the number of function calls it makes.

```
function win(n)
   if n ≤ 3 let memo(n) = 'yes'
   if memo(n-2) = 'no' or memo(n-3) = 'no' let memo(n) = 'yes'
   else let memo(n) = 'no'
   let win(n) = memo(n)
```

> Roughly, what is the number of steps that this program uses to compute $\mathit{win}(n)$? Is $\mathrm{step}(n)$ linear in $n$, polynomial in $n$ or exponential in $n$? Is it feasible to use this code to calculate $\mathit{win}(1000)$ on a fast supercomputer? Justify your answer.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: I don't think the program is correct. This is not how you implement memoization.

Answer (score 3):

First, let me correct the program:

```
1 function win(n)
2     if memo(n) exists:
3         return memo(n)
4     if n ≤ 3:
5         memo(n) = true
6     else:
7         memo(n) = not win(n-2) or not win(n-3)
8     return memo(n)
```

Compared to your code, there are two main differences:

1. If the value of the function is already known, that it is immediately returned (lines 2–3).
2. Otherwise, we compute the value of the function recursively by invoking *win* rather than *memo* (line 7).

The running time of *win* depends on which values have already been calculated. For example, if you already computed the value of *win* on $n-2$ and $n-3$, then computing it on $n$ takes time $O(1)$. We can also bound the running time of *win* on input $n$ by $O(n)$, since lines 4–8 run at most once for every value of the input.

We could also implement *win* without any memoization:

```
1 function win(n)
2     if n ≤ 3:
3          return true
4     else:
5          return not win(n-2) or not win(n-3)
```

The running time of this implementation satisfies the recurrence
$$ T(n) = T(n-2) + T(n-3) + O(1), $$
with base case $T(n) = O(1)$ for $n \leq 3$. Using standard techniques, we determine that the running time is $\Theta(c^n)$, where $c \approx 1.3247$ is the unique real root of $c^3=c+1$.

Finally, let us take a look at some values of *win*:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccccccccccc}
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\\hline
\mathit{win}(n) & T & T & T & T & F & F & T & T & T & F & F & T & T & T & F & F
\end{array}
$$
Notice the period of 5. We can easily prove the following formula by induction: for $n \neq 1$, $\mathit{win}(n)$ holds iff $n \bmod 5 \in \{0,1\}$. This gives an $O(1)$ algorithm for computing *win*.